# Url.Content type method in class library code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this code in a class library:

```
string.Format("{0}://{1}", Current.Request.Url.Scheme, Current.Request.Url.Authority);
```

This works fine if the application is deployed in the root domain and not a subdomain.

I would like to adapt the above to work for a sub domain as well. In the razor code I can just use:

```
Url.Content("~/")
```

Is there an equivalent for this for class libraries ('web independent' C# code)?

Comment: Do you need to form a fully-qualified URL, e.g. `'http://www.example.com/controller/action'`, or an application root-relative URL, e.g. `'/controller/action'`?

Comment: I think I found a way. I could use: System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath to get the 'bit' I need

Comment: Yes, and append `'/'` if the ApplicationPath is a sub-folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This little function will get the application root folder, e.g. `'/'` or `'/sub-folder/'`:

```
string GetAppRootFolder()
{
    var appRootFolder = HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath.ToLower();

    if (!appRootFolder.EndsWith("/"))
    {
        appRootFolder += "/";
    }

    return appRootFolder;
}
```